# I did a login form but i got a problem which was my password accept both lower case letter and upper case letter

Tags: php, mysql, session, input, passwords

I did login form but i got a problem which was my password accept both lower case letter and upper case letter. Can anyone tell me how to fix this issue.

```
<?php
include("config.php");
if(isset($_POST['login']))
  {
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    $qry="select * from admin where username='$username' and password='$password'";
    $res=mysqli_query($con,$qry);
    $len=mysqli_num_rows($res);
    if($len>=1)
      {
        $user_id=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)['id'];
        $_SESSION['user_id']=$user_id;
        $_SESSION['message']=$user_id;
        $_SESSION['logout']="";
        echo"<script>"; 
        echo"window.location.href='admin/dashboard.php';";
        echo"</script>";
      }
}
```

?>

Comment: Don't store passwords in plain text. Instead, use [`password_hash`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash) and [`password_verify`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to store and check them.

Comment: Please also be aware that you should **NEVER** use user input directly in SQL statements! You should use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead, binding your `$_POST` variables to parameters. Given your code above, you have a serious security vulnerability. You can refer to [**this post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) for further information on how to prevent SQL injection in PHP :)

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)['id']` < that I feel won't do what you're probably wanting to get and it's its "id", right? The question's unclear.

Answer (score -1):

1. Do not store password as-is. Use some hash instead and compare just hashed password with stored hashed password.
2. By default MySQL uses case-insensitive collation. You can change it though but it doesn't make sense in this case. The right algorithm is:

   - select user by username or password on database side
   - compare password hashes on PHP side
     In this case you don't care about field case sensitivity. The hash of the string in upper case will be different from the hash of the string in lower case.

By the way, your code is vulnerable against SQL injection. I recommend to use prepared statements.